# Injecting Cache as dependency in a Eloquent model laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I need to use the Cache functionality in a Eloquent model, but i don`t want to use the Cache Facade. It's *not* possible to inject it through the constructor.

So how would i do this without using the Facade? What is best practice?

Comment: Depends what you’re trying to do. An Eloquent model is for fetching and persisting data, it _shouldn’t_ know about anything like caching. Instead, create a service class that wraps the Eloquent model, but does any caching you need.

Comment: It's a Nested Set Model and has a lot of different/diversified locale and slug attributes, depending on the request data. Caching these attributes is a major speed improvement, but can only be done inside the model. I agree that having a service is a clean solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as Cache;

class MyModel extends Model {
    public function myMethod(Cache $cache) {
        $cache->put('foo', 'bar', 1000);
    } 
}
```

You can find a list for the concrete implementations of every facade here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades#facade-class-reference

Comment: Injecting it like this unfortunately does not work (for attributes). When its a method, i can call this method with Cache as a param, but that is not what i want to do.